# how to get the name of a button created by QDialogButtonBox?

Tags: c++, qt, button, widget

I'm trying get all the button child widgets of a window. The buttons were created through **QDialogButtonBox**. How do I get the which one is the cancel/ok/save button?

I have:

```
QWidget *pWin = QApplication::activeWindow();
QList<QPushButton *> allPButtons = pWin->findChildren<QPushButton *>();
QListIterator<QPushButton*> i(allPButtons);
while( i.hasNext() )
{
  //identify which button is cancel/ok/save button here
  /*Note: This is where I'm having trouble, getting the text of the 
    button here returns NULL. Any other way of Identifying which is 
    which?
    Is it a special case when buttons are created through QDialogButtonBox?       
   */
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [QDialogButtonBox::button()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qdialogbuttonbox.html#button) method, to get the button of the corresponding [role](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qdialogbuttonbox.html#StandardButton-enum).

For instance :

```
QPushButton* pOkButton = pButtonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok);
QPushButton* pCancelButton = pButtonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);
// and so on...
```

Generally speaking, I would say it's a bad idea to find a button from it's text, as this text might change when you app is internationalized.

Comment: How do you get the button role of a button? could you please give me an example?

Comment: You have to start from your `QDialogButtonBox` object (in your question, you are using `pWin->findChildren`, and I don't understand why). From your `QDialogButtonBox` object, you can get the roles of the displayed buttons with the `standardButtons` property.

Comment: ..or if you have a pointer to a `QPushButton` which is displayed by the `QDialogButtonBox`, you can get its role with `QDialogButtonBox::buttonRole(pPushButton)`.

Comment: I'm trying to get all the buttons in the currently active window, that's why I'm using pWin->findChildren. I'll try your suggestion... thanks... :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is by `text` parameter from constructor such as `QPushButton(const QString & text, QWidget * parent = 0)`:

```
QPushButton* buttonSave = new QPushButton("Save");
// etc..
while( i.hasNext() )
{
  //identify which button is cancel/ok/save button here
  if(i.next()->text() == "Save") {
    // do something to save push button
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting the text returns an empty string. :(

Comment: Owen: you have to assign a text string to the button when you instantiate it.

Comment: Buttons created through QDialogButtonBox need no text to be assigned, just pass what buttons you like to appear and it labels them itself. I just don't get it why it returns an empty string when I get the button's text...

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution:

Use QDialogButtonBox's [buttons](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#buttons) function to return a list of all the buttons that have been added to the button box, then iterate over the list and identify each button using QDialogButtonBox's [standardButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#standardButton).

```
auto buttons = ui->buttonBox->buttons();
for (auto button : buttons) {
    switch (ui->buttonBox->standardButton(button)) {
    case QDialogButtonBox::Ok:
        // do something
        break;
    case QDialogButtonBox::Cancel:
        // do something
        break;
    case QDialogButtonBox::Save:
        // do something
        break;        
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

**For non-standard buttons**

Map each button to an enum:

**.h** file:

```
private:
   enum class NonStandardButton { Undo, Redo };

   // map of non-standard buttons to enum class NonStandardButton
   QHash<QAbstractButton*, NonStandardButton> buttonsMap;
```

**.cpp** file:

```
// in constructor
auto undoQPushButton =
        ui->buttonBox->addButton("Undo", QDialogButtonBox::ActionRole);
auto redoQPushButton =
        ui->buttonBox->addButton("Redo", QDialogButtonBox::ActionRole);


buttonsMap.insert(undoQPushButton, NonStandardButton::Undo);
buttonsMap.insert(redoQPushButton, NonStandardButton::Redo);
```

Then use `QDialogButtonBox::NoButton` to identify non-standard buttons:

```
switch (ui->buttonBox->standardButton(button)) {    
    case QDialogButtonBox::NoButton:
        switch (buttonsMap.value(button)) {
        case NonStandardButton::Undo:
            // do something
            break;
        case NonStandardButton::Redo:
            // do something
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    default:
        break;
}
```